# How to print a text without substring in Python

Tags: python, text

I want to search for a word in the text and then print the text without that word. For example, we have the text "I was with my friend", I want the text be "I with my friend". I have done the following so far:

```
text=re.compile("[^was]")   
val = "I was with my friend"
if text.search(val): 
    print text.search(val) #in this line it is obvious wrong
else:
    print 'no'
```

Comment: can you please clarify is you want to remove ANY occurrence of the word or just the first one?

Comment: Unless python has some weird regex format, `[^was]` is going to match any single character that isn't `w`, `a`, or `s`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
val = "I was with my friend"

print val.replace("was ", "")
```

Output:

```
I with my friend
```

Comment: if you replace it with a `space` you end up with two spaces one after the other, as in the printout

Comment: I think the OP wants to look for a word (i.e. a string beginning and ending with whitespace), not a string. If that is the case, your answer is incorrect.

Comment: `'With my friend, I was.'`

Comment: Jason see @PeterWood 's example above. Also, the OP might want to completely remove any occurrence of the word, more than once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove what you've found using a regular expression:

```
match = text.search(val)
if match is not None:
    print val.replace(match.group(0), "")
```

(However, if you were searching for the word *was* then your pattern is wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Substitute an empty string if matched.

```
text=re.compile(r"was")   
val = "I was with my friend"
if text.search(val): 
    print text.sub('',val)
else:
    print 'no'
```

or you can split by match and join again.

```
if text.search(val):
    print(''.join(text.split(val)))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
print val[:val.index('was')] + val[val.index('was ') + 4:]
```

This example assumes that word is `was`. But you can define a variable and use that variable

```
search_word = 'was'
print val[:val.index(search_word)] + val[val.index(search_word) + len(search_word) + 1:]
```

Also, this only works for the first occurrence of the `search_word` and doesn't do any validation if it contains the word or not

Answer (score -1):

to search a substring simply do

```
if 'was' in 'i was with my friend':
  print ...
```